# SCSS: if my variable has a numerical increment, how do I access it in a loop?

Tags: css, variables, sass, preprocessor

For people to understand my problem, I'll start with an example.

This is an example of an SCSS `for` loop that dynamically generates declarations for `h1` to `h6` tags with incrementing sizes:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {

    h#{$h} {
        font-size: ($i + 1em) - $i/6; // not real
    }
}
```

I understand that the usage of `#{$var}` is for escaping so when I have `h#{$h}` I'm basically generating *h1 to h6*, right? but that's what I understand for non-variable entries like html tags...

How would I do it for variables though?
For example, I have cascading variables of grey:

```
$g01: #DDD;
$g02: #999;
$g03: #666;
```

then I want to construct a for loop for a `.text-grey-$var` class like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {

    .text-grey-#{$i} {
        // color: ???; // How to do it? 
    }
}
```

How do I do it?

This below didn't work (I believe for obvious reasons):

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {

    .text-grey-#{$i} {
        color: $g0#{$i};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using List instead, example code snippet for your case:

```scss
$g0: (#DDD, #999, #666);

@for $i from 1 through 3 {
    .text-grey-#{$i} {
        color: nth($g0, $i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also loop through the length of the list `through list.length($g0)`